# Update Mapping In Other Smart Contract

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


   contract SomeStore{

    struct SomeInfo{
        uint256 id;
        address[] players;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => SomeInfo) public myData;

    function updateMyData(uint256 i, address[] memory a) external {
        SomeInfo memory d = SomeInfo({
            lotteryId : i,
            players : a
        });
        myData[i] = d;
    }

    function getData() public pure returns(uint256){
        return 2;
    }}

    contract Storage {

        function storeInOther(SomeStore _s) external {
            address[] memory sz = new address[](0);
            sz[0] = msg.sender;
            _s.updateMyData(1, sz);
        }

        function hh(SomeStore _s) external pure returns (uint256){
            return _s.getData();
        }
    }
```

i want to use the SomeStore as the contract that just hold the mapping which old some data. which i want to update from my Storage Contract. When i try to call getData from the Storage Contract it works it returns me 2.

But when i try to call the storeInOther function which calls the updateMyData from SomeStore the transaction fails. I tried this in remix

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things wrong here.

1. Change  `lotteryId : i` to `id : i` since id is the name of variable.
2. Not sure what you are trying to do inside the `getData()` function but it will always return 2!
3. Your function exacution fails since you are trying to create and pass dynamic memory array inside the function. It is not allowed.

> In Solidity it is not possible to create dynamic arrays in memory.

You can read more [here](https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/memory_array_building.html#:%7E:text=In%20Solidity%20it%20is%20not,the%20length%20for%20our%20array.)

Here is the code I have that works. Notice how I changed dynamic array to sized one.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


   contract SomeStore{

    struct SomeInfo{
        uint256 id;
        address[] players;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => SomeInfo) public myData;

    function updateMyData(uint256 i, address[] memory a) external {
        SomeInfo memory d = SomeInfo({
            id : i,
            players : a
        });
        myData[i] = d;
    }

    function getData() public pure returns(uint256){
        return 2;
    }}

    contract Storage {
        
        function storeInOther(address _addr) public  {

            SomeStore _s = SomeStore(_addr);
            address[] memory sz = new address[](1);
            sz[0] = msg.sender;
            _s.updateMyData(1, sz);
        }

        function hh(SomeStore _s) external pure returns (uint256){
            return _s.getData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand this :) . One Quick Question
Is it efficient to have a separate contract like SomeStore to hold data like myData mapping and then use it other contracts ?